# How can I convert a C# application that uses StandardInput and StandardOutput in .NET Compact Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I have an application that uses the Process class, StandardInput, and StandardOutput to communicate with an external executable.  I am using this to pass strings back and forth, and it works well in my Windows application.

On the mobile device, I do not see StandardInput or StandardOutput in the Process class.  Is there an easy way to replicate this functionality on the Mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Not much of an answer but under certain very limited scenarios you could use command line arguments.  They can be retrieved using.

```
Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I think I'm going to just dump all of the info into a file and then call the other app.